# SQL query to print mirror labels

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to print labels in words as returned by a SQL query such as follow.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

When I want to print the reverse of those labels, I have to print them as follow

```
3 2 1
6 5 4
```

In my real case, I have 5 colums by 2 rows, how can I formulate my query so that my records are ordered like the second one.
The normal ordering is handled by word, so my query is like

`SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY Products.id`

I'm using MS Access =(

EDIT :

Just to make it clear

I'd like my records to be ordered such as

```
3 2 1 6 5 4 9 8 7 12 11 10
```

EDIT2 :

my table looks like this

```
ID    ProductName
1     Product1
2     Product2
3     Product3
n     Product[n]
```

I want the ids to be returned as I mentioned above

Comment: I am not sure how you want them formatted, from what I can make out *SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY Products.id desc;* should work? If it isn't a pure ordering function, why not just select the columns for the query in reverse?

Comment: Can you please give the table structure that you are querying, possibly with a few rows of example data, and show how that data should be returned? I can't understand what you are wanting based on the example above I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY Products.id desc
```

Alternately if your query at the moment is really giving you this:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from products order by products.id;
```

why not use

```
select col3, col2, col1 from products order by products.id;
```